# $|(z_0-w_1)...(z_0-w_n)|=1$ for some $z_0$ in the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{D}=\{z\in \mathbb{C} \,\,|\,\,|z|<1\}$. Prove that, if $\{w_1, \,...\,,w_n\}\subset\mathbb{D}$, then there exists a point $z_0\in \mathbb{D}$ such that:

$$|(z_0-w_1)...(z_0-w_n)|=1$$

[Hint: use the Cauchy inequalities or the maximum modulus principle]

My idea initially was to prove, somehow, that $\exists\alpha\in\partial\mathbb{D}$ with $|P(\alpha)|>1$, where $P(z)=(z-w_1)...(z-w_n)$. If that is true, than from the maximum modulus principle:

$$\sup_{z\in\mathbb{D}}|P(z)|=\max_{z\in\partial\mathbb{D}}|P(z)|>1$$

That means $|P(\beta)|>1$ for some $\beta\in\mathbb{D}$ close enough to the border. Since $|P(0)|=|w_1|...|w_n|<1$ and |P| is continuous, from the intermediate value theorem, $|P(z_0)|=1$ for some $z_0\in\mathbb{D}$.

But I'm having trouble to prove that such $\alpha$ exists. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider the polynomial $Q(z) = z^n\cdot P(1/z)$.

Comment: Sorry, @DanielFischer, I can't see how it follows. I read the duplicate as well, but still couldn't figure it out completely. I noticed that $|Q(z)|=|P(\bar{z})|$ for all $z\in\partial\mathbb{D}$, so $\max_{z\in\mathbb{D}}|Q(z)|=\max_{z\in\mathbb{D}}|P(z)|$. But I couldn't find out anything about $\max_{z\in\mathbb{D}}|Q(z)|$. Can we conclude it is $>1$? (by the way, I think if we just conclude it is $\geq 1$ it still won't solve my problem, since I'm looking for a $z_0$ with $|P(z_0)|=1$ in the interior of the disk, not on the boundary)

Comment: $Q$ is not constant - unless $w_0 = \dotsc = w_n = 0$, but then the assertion is false, there is no $z_0 \in \mathbb{D}$ with $\lvert z_0^n\rvert = 1$ - and we have $Q(0) = 1$. The maximum modulus principle thus tells us there is a $z_1 \in \partial \mathbb{D}$ with $\lvert Q(z_1)\rvert > 1$. But then $\lvert P(1/z_1)\rvert > 1$.